# MYSQL/PHP: Return one element of results array using JSON

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, multidimensional-array

When a query returns one row and I convert it into JSON, I get:

Case 1:

```
{"comment":[{"response":"I totally agree"}]}
```

However, when a query returns more than one row and is converted into JSON, I get:

Case 2:

```
{"comment":[{"response":"I totally agree"},{"response":"You must be kidding"}]}
```

Assuming I just want the first row, how can I convert the JSON in case 2 to the form of Case 1.  Happy to use PHP or do something in the MYSQL query.
The query and code to create the JSON looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT response
FROM comments 
WHERE MATCH(comments) AGAINST('$query' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $return[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode(array('comment'=>$return));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$sql = "SELECT response
FROM comments 
WHERE MATCH(comments) AGAINST('$query' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)";

echo json_encode(array('comment'=>mysql_fetch_assoc($res)));
```

Comment: For clarification, mysql_fetch_assoc() retrieves one row at a time, so calling it once will only get the first row. Also, you should be using mysqli not mysql, as mysql has been deprecated: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php